# Как переместить таблицу с колонкой Long?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

У меня есть таблица с колонкой типа `Long`.
Пытаюсь сделать

```
alter table Table_Name move tablespace New_Tablespace
```

Получаю ошибку

> ORA-00997: illegal use of long datatype

Как можно изменить `tablespace` у таблицы с колонкой `long` без использования утилит импорта\экспорта?

Comment: Я бы в первую очередь попытался избавиться от `long` - например конвертировать его в `CLOB/BLOB`. Приложения использующие эту таблицу, возможно придется править... Перенести в другое табличное пространство можно командой `copy` (sqlplus)

Comment: Таблиц больше чем одна, хотелось разобраться с ними массово не правя клиент

Comment: Oracle советовал переходить с `LONG/LONG RAW` на `CLOB/BLOB` еще с какой-то там 8-й версии, т.е. более 15 лет назад... По-моему пришло время прислушаться ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак. Нельзя перемещать таблицу с колонкой Long из одного tablespace в другое.

Альтернативным вариантом может быть создание второй таблицы по принципу 
`create table_new selec * from table_old` и последующим `drop` и `rename`.

При это важно следить за всеми `FK`, триггерами и прочим хранимым кодом, ссылающимся на таблицу.